# Clickable HTML table executes MySQL insert statement (PHP, Possibly JavaScript)

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html-table

I've got a HTML table that's populated by a select query from a MySQL table (using the values First_name, Last_name, PhoneNumber).

What I need is for these rows to be clickable, and upon being clicked, executing an "Insert into receivers_table (ReceiverNumber) values (PhoneNumber from said row), how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Show the code that you have so far.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what types of questions are useful to ask here. Do not come here expecting people to do your coding for you for free. We expect that you have attempted to solve your own problem and in doing so, will post what you have tried and what has not worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you need to do two things:

1. Make a server-side PHP page that performs the database operation.  In PHP, read the ReceiverNumber from `$_POST` or `$_GET` and put that value into a SQL query, using your choice of SQL library.  (In production, make sure you sanitize/validate the value to prevent [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).)

   ```
   $phonenum = $_POST['PhoneNumber'];
   //do validation, submit SQL query to DB...
   ```
2. Bind `click` event handlers to the table rows that make an Ajax call to the PHP page you created.  You can do this easily in jQuery (assuming the `<tr>` tags are in a table with ID "receivertable" and the `<td>` cells with the numbers have the class "recnum"):

   ```
   $("#receivertable tr").bind("click", function() {
       $.post('newreceiver.php', {
           PhoneNumber: $(this).children("td.recnum").text()
       });
   });
   ```

If you're not using jQuery, you can use `addEventListener("click", function(){...})` on your table rows and create an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XmlHttpRequest) object to perform the Ajax call.  Getting the data from the table row is done via DOM traversal, e.g, `document.getElementById("receivertable").childNodes[2].textContent`.